# User Friendly way to use formula for calculation

Tags: c#, parsing, excel-formula

I have an object model that I need the user to be able to create a formula based on, and also use some built-in functions. For example:

```
AddWorkDays(MyObject.StartDate, 3)
```

MyObject has various properties that the user may access. We may also need to do some If/Then statements. The users are very familiar with Excel formulas, because that is how they currently do their work.

I see two possible options:

1. create my own parser using one of the many available C# Libraries
2. Adapt an Excel-based parser to be context aware of my objects.

The issue with option 1 is I don't want to re-invent the wheel. I would expect someone has already built a parser that can handle basic functions and math operations and is context aware based on class(es) passed in. I can't seem to find something like this.

Option 2 would allow the user to re-use their existing Excel knowledge to build formulas like:

```
=if(MyObject.Type = "A", AddWorkDays(MyObject.StartDate, 3), AddWorkDays(MyObject.StartDate, 5)
```

I see XLParser is advertised as being great for parsing Excel formulas, but it seems I would need to add-on the Context-aware part for reading and validating properties on MyObject.

Any experience, examples, warnings, etc. on how to proceed are welcome

Comment: Define Context aware, also this is a little off topic as this will likely end up with library suggestion

Comment: Added some clarification. I understand it may not be directly on topic, but there are many other posts working on one parser, and people then suggest a different parser or method. I'm perfectly happy to be pointed to another question that has already handled this! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using the FLEE library: https://github.com/mparlak/Flee

It supports "Context" where you can define variables that should be in context. Out of the box it supports regular syntax for things like addition, subtraction, and even a basic IF statement. It is easily extensible to add your own functions. I made it Excel-like by defining some of the common functions: AND, OR, MIN, MAX. This was less than 100 lines of code to do.

I use it to process relatively large data sets (200,000 items with 5 formulas for each item) and it processes in under 10 seconds if used correctly.